# Repeat or close program?

Tags: python, loops, repeat

I tried out my own little Caesar cipher and it works pretty nice until now ... I want to add that after the procedure is over the interface asks the user if he want to do the procedure again or not, but I am failing ...

Here is my code so far :

```
print("Willkommen zur Caesarchiffre!")

def my_func() :

    MAX_KEY_SIZE = 26

    def getMode():
        while True:
            print('Wollen sie verschlüsseln(v) oder entschlüsseln(e) ?')
            mode = input().lower()
            if mode in 'verschlüsseln v entschlüsseln e'.split():
                return mode
            else:
                print('Bitte geben sie entweder "v" zum verschlüsseln oder "e" zum entschlüsseln ein .')

    def getMessage():
        print('Geben sie ihre Nachricht ein:')
        return input()

    def getKey():
        key = 0
        while True:
            print('Geben sie die Zahl der Verschiebung(en) an. (1-%s)' % (MAX_KEY_SIZE))
            key = int(input())
            if (key >= 1 and key <= MAX_KEY_SIZE):
                return key

    def getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key):
        if mode[0] == 'e':
            key = -key
        translated = ''

        for symbol in message:
            if symbol.isalpha():
                num = ord(symbol)
                num += key

                if symbol.isupper():
                    if num > ord('Z'):
                        num -= 26
                    elif num < ord('A'):
                        num += 26
                elif symbol.islower():
                    if num > ord('z'):
                        num -= 26
                    elif num < ord('a'):
                        num += 26

                translated += chr(num)
            else:
                translated += symbol
        return translated

    mode = getMode()
    message = getMessage()
    key = getKey()

    print('Ihr Text lautet:')
    print(getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key))
```

I dont know how to loop the whole program ...

I´m not native English so the display text of the print("")s is not English

**edit:**

Here is the extract I mentioned in the comment:

```
               return translated
while True :
        mode = getMode()
            if mode = 'b'
                break
        message = getMessage()
        key = getKey()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to repeat forever until the user decides to exit, e.g.:

```
while True:
  mode = getMode()
  if mode == 'q': 
    break
  message = getMessage()
  key = getKey()
```

so he'll choose between `v`, `e` and `q` for quit

Comment: maybe i am just to tired right know or i am to stupid but where do i have to put which code ? Because if i just paste the code at the end of mine i get a error which says:

 ` in <module>
    mode = getMode()
NameError: name 'getMode' is not defined`

Comment: go to sleep and try to indent your code correctly tomorrow

Comment: i guess i got what you mean (i oaste it in the answer i cant in comment) like this ?